# Why do we consider a rectangle as a closed loop while deriving the magnetic field of a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

Why do we consider a rectangle as a closed loop while deriving the magnetic field of a infinitely long conducting solenoid. I think I could have any other shape. How does it affect if I take another shape ?

Comment: Your other question is quite related. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396273/why-do-we-consider-a-circle-as-a-closed-loop-while-deriving-the-magnetic-field-o

Answer (score 1):

In the infinite solenoid, using the symmetry along the axial coordinate we can show that the magnetic field is along the axis. We use a rectangular loop because since the fields are along the axis, $\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=|B||dl|\cos(0^{\circ})=|B||dl|$ if $\vec{dl}$ is long the axis, and $0$ if $\vec{dl}$ is perpendicular to the axis. This makes finding the magnitude of the field easier with rectangular ampere loops.

In theory, you can use any random shape of the loop to find the field, but extracting the value of the fields from them would be very difficult.